# What causes this jsp Error 500?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I wrote a very simple jsp problem that gets a number from a class and show it but I encountered error 500.

I use eclipse with tomcat 5.5:

```
 <%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<h1>number of shown :</h1>
<body>
<%
try{
out.print(Model.getCount());
}
catch(IOException k)
{
    out.println("Eror");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

my Model class=>

```
public class Model {
    static int number=0;
    public static int getCount()
    {
        number++;
        return number;
    }
}
```

any my model class is default package.

The error I see:

> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 14 in the
>   jsp file: /show.jsp Model cannot be
>   resolved 11:  12: <% 13: try{
>   14: out.print(Model.getCount()); 15: }
>   16: catch(IOException k) 17: {
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:93)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:328)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:307)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:309)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root
>   cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/5.5.33 logs.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never put any class in the default package. The default package is not accessible to classes in a package, and since the JSP is transformed in a servlet class by Tomcat, and this class is in a package, it can't access your Model class.

Once it's in a well-defined package, you'll have to import it, as mschonaker shows in his answer:

```
<%@page import="somepackage.Model"%>
```

Comment: -1 next time comment on my answer so I can improve it. My answer wasn't incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: Commenting could have left the OP in the dark until you read your comments, and your response was incorrect: it suggested importing the class whereas the OP said explicitely in his question that the Model class was in default package. So, next time, read the question carefully before answering. You should be happy to have had 3 upvotes for an unhelpful answer, whereas I had one downvote for a helpful one.

Comment: honestly the first paragraph of "jb nizet" was helpfull for me no second that include from mschonaker because it was helpfull for me unrecognization of jsp about default package.

Comment: anyway, it's awkward having an accepted answer with negative score. Putting that to zero.

Answer (score 4):

It can't find class `Model`.

Try something like:

```
          <%@page import="somepackage.Model"%>
```