# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, package, web.xml, java-package

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP
```

Ok, there are lots of articles about this error and i'm still a newbie.
I sow that this error might be caused by some different kind of reasons and this is my (likely either stupid or already existent) reason:

It  doesn't find the class, apparently imported from NetBeans.

```
<%@ page import="mypack.Display" %>
```

In fact, if i have a look to the cache file "index_jsp.java" the issue is just on the line where there's "*import mypack.Display;*".
My problem is so similar to this [What causes this jsp Error 500?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640089/what-causes-this-jsp-error-500) with the difference that i didn't put *mypack.Display* into the default package, then i don't know why there's this error.

This is my **index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><% out.print("jsp class test");%></h1>
        <%@ page import="mypack.Display" %>   
        <%
            Display t = new Display();
            t.test("Roby");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the simple  **Display.java**

```
package mypack;

public class Display{

  public void test(String msg){
    System.out.println("My name is "+msg);
  }
 }
```

A friend of mine, said me that i should configure the *servlet* into the *web.xml* file into the WEB-INF folder, but looking the samples i didn't understand how i can do it.
Do i have to mapping the package into that file?

I put the *Display.java* under the package "mypack" correctly taken by Netbeans, in fact if i try to change either the class or the package name, both in the index.jsp and Display.java, the compiler shows me an error.

Could someone help me please for a better understanding?

Below the complete error:

```
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. mypack.Display resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Display cannot be resolved to a type
16:         <%--<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "mypack.Display" />--%>
17:         <%@ page import="mypack.Display" %>   
18:         <%
19:             Display t = new Display();
20:             t.test("Roby");
21: //          out.println(outpt);
22:         %>


An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Display cannot be resolved to a type
16:         <%--<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "mypack.Display" />--%>
17:         <%@ page import="mypack.Display" %>   
18:         <%
19:             Display t = new Display();
20:             t.test("Roby");
21: //          out.println(outpt);
22:         %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.
```

Comment: Try to move that `<%@ page import="mypack.Display" %>` to the top of the page. Maybe tomcat has some problems with imports in the middle of the page. Otherwise your Display class in not visible in the JSP. Try to remove app from the server clean/build project and redeploy.